# PHP should I write comments/documentation

Tags: php, coding-style

Once I've read in the "Clean Code" book that comments shouldn't be written because they mess up the code.

On the second hand however, "kohana" code (as one of many) contains extensive documentations and comments before almost every line of code.

I'm creating the project which will be used by user-programmers in the future...how should I write comments then?

To make this more clear - should I:

- Write documentation before each class ?
- Write documentation before each method ?
- Write @param, @return... for each method ?
- Write comments for almost every line of code to make it more clear ?

Comment: Sorry, but not a real question. there's no right/wrong answer, and it's just going to degrade into personal opinion.

Comment: Well, I can see now that you're probably right...I don't know if I should delete this question...but it was good to read some opinions :P

Comment: This would probably fit better over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `Once I've read in the "Clean Code" book that comments shouldn't be written because they mess up the code.`  Can you provide more detail here?  Perhaps an excerpt?  I'm not sure the book even actually says this, based on the reviews I've found so far.

Comment: The whole "comments" part. It says they should be written as rarely as possible, and it would be great if there were none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should:

- Write documentation before each class
- Write documentation before each method
- Write @param, @return... for each public method

Comments on every line of code aren't too necessary, but I recommend them on lines of code which would otherwise be unclear or obscure.

Answer (score 1):

I write comments/documentation in two major cases:

- When something the program does isn't **immediately obvious**. Even if it looks obvious now, it won't be in 6 months, or to another guy trying to maintain your work.
- When the variable/argument/property types aren't clear. That's when I add a docblock.

Most (all) decent IDEs have mechanisms for collapsing and even hiding comments. Don't give them up because a book told you so, or because you think it's "messy".

Messy is a subjective term. I'd argue writing one comment line can save 10 hours of headache to future you.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I would consider future readers. Will they benefit from the comments?  In my own case, I have only regretted the comments that I failed to write and rarely the unnecessary comments that I did. Many times I've thought "there's no way I'll forget this"... and did.

As an alternative, you can also maintain a separate copy of the code with full commenting, and a release version where you remove most/all comments.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever book you read that said comments shouldn't be written, you should immediately throw away and forget about forever. I don't care if you are the only person who will ever be working with the code, you should still document it.

To me, if you are working on code that will be used by other developers, I would try to stick with the PHPDoc (JavaDoc) style of documentation, which means you document every class, method, property, etc. as thoroughly as possible.  One benefit this gives is that a lot of IDE's will actually use this information for code completion, making your application even easier to work with.

Now within code blocks themselves, I don't think you need to comment every line (especially lines where it is readily apparent what you are doing), but it is useful to comment different sections of the code, different logic branches, etc.

Also one non-comment thing I would also suggest, is using variable names that are meaningful to their purpose (with the exception of simple counters).  Oftentimes people get cute and want to use 3-4 letter variable names, because of some misplaced opinion that it will same them loads of time in typing, or make their code shorter.  If you need a long name like `product_catalog_iterator` to describe a class, to me that is better than `prodcatit` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a believer in not writing comments. Instead writing code that is self commenting. What I mean by that is your functions and variables describe what they do. For example you could write it two ways:

```
function foo1($a, $b, $c){
 return md5($a . $b . $c);
}
```

or you could write

```
function encryption($pepper, $content, $salt){
 return md5($pepper . $content . $salt);
}
```

In this example the first one you have no idea what it's doing, but the 2nd, one you know exactly what it's doing. The only time I feel comments are needed is after you write really hacky code that took you a long time to figure out how to do it and isn't very clear what it is doing. This however should be far and in between.

The reason documentation isn't a good idea, is because what generally happens is you write great comments for when the function is first created and then after bug fixes and maintenance. The comments were never updated and now that comments are saying something the function doesn't do and offers confusion instead of help.

Comment: I have no idea where the $a, $b, $c came from in the second example. Maybe you should comment it? :P

Comment: I'm sorry. That's what I get for copy and paste! I fixed it.